# How can I include an html file in my page by clicking on a button ?

Tags: javascript, html, button, include

I'm trying to get a page with a simple button that will load the content of another html page on click.

```
<input type="button" value="Create a square" id="send" onClick="createaquare()" />
```

What i want is that when i click on the button, the function create a square that is called loads another html file that contains a simple square.

```
    <div></div>

<style type="text/css">

div
{
    height : 200px;
    width : 200px;
    background: red;
    opacity : 0.3;
}
```

And each time I click on the button, another square appears. How is that possible using javascript or jquery, ajax, or anyting?

Thank you

Comment: Does it have to load another page or can the button click simply generate a new square?

Comment: Yes I'm simply trying to generate a new square but i thought it was the better thing to do, to avoid loading the square when the page initially loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than incur another HTTP call and the complexity of having to go get the contents of a file that will always be the same, it's much better to just generate the squares upon the button click.

By giving all the new divs their own CSS class, you can style them all the same, while leaving all the original divs alone.

Just to be clear, in my example I'm adding the same content to each new square, but if you were to add conditional logic to the click event handler, you can create different content in different squares according to your own logic.

Inject content into the squares using the `textContent` property if it is just straight text you want added and use the `innerHTML` property if you want to inject content that needs to be parsed (i.e. your content contains markup -- for example when I add the text "ESPN" to the link, I'm also adding an HTML `<br>` element).

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btnMakeSquare");

var counter = 1;

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Create a new square and configure it:
  var newSquare = document.createElement("div");
  newSquare.id = "newDiv" + counter;
  newSquare.textContent = newSquare.id;
  newSquare.setAttribute("class", "newDiv");
  
  // Now create content for that square (this can be anything)
  var newLink = document.createElement("a");
  newLink.href = "http://espn.com";
  newLink.innerHTML = "<br>ESPN";
  newLink.id = "link" + counter;
  
  // Put the link into the square:
  newSquare.appendChild(newLink);
  
  // Bump up the counter:
  counter++;
  
  // Inject the square (which now contains a link) into the DOM:
  document.body.appendChild(newSquare);
  

});
```

```css
/* Only the one original div will be affected by this: */
#originalDiv {
    height : 50px;
    width : 50px;
    background: red;
    opacity : 0.3;

}

/* All generated divs will have the following class 
   so they will all look the same. But, none of the
   original divs will have this class, so they won't
   be affected.                                      */
.newDiv {
    height : 75px;
    width : 75px;
    background: blue;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:.1.5em;
    color:yellow;
    text-align:center;
}

/* This only affects links in new squares */
.newDiv > a{
  color:green;

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Create a square" id="btnMakeSquare">
<div id="originalDiv">I'm the original div</div>
```

Comment: Should `div` selector at `css` reference dynamic `counter` `id`s, to exclude applying styles at `css` to all `div` elements in `document`?

Comment: If you don't want all the new squares to look like the original div, just change the CSS selector to the original `div` element's `id` then it will only apply to that one. Let me update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very clear and complete. But if the future, i would like to insert a lot of elements in the squares, is this solution still useful? I mean, i want to create squares that contains php variables values for exemple. I know it's not my initial question but it is one of the reasons that made me think it was better to include another file, so i can include every elements in the square at the same time.

Comment: You can populate any of the content with whatever other content you wish. I'll update the answer again to show that it's just a matter of nesting elements.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the best solution. I'll try to use this with my code. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: All I dislike on this is the global counter. The btn could be skipped since it aint resued tho.

Comment: @Lain Not sure what you are saying here. The counter doesn't need to be in global scope, but it does need to have a higher scope than the `click` event handler to avoid being reset upon each button click. In reality, all of the code would be in a module or using the module pattern. Also, the button was a requirement of the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant as now - in global scope - seeing a variable 'counter' could be anything. Just for a third person maintainer I would prefer something like 'squareCounter'. However a man is correct, it is irrelevant in this example.

Comment: None of the answers posted on SO are ever "complete", as in it encompass what the totality of the code should be. It is incumbent on the OPs to take those answers and incorporate them into their own code bases.

Comment: @Scott Marcus: Yes you are right. I am kinda new here -  so I probably exaggerate. No offense meant by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<iframes>` to load another webpage on your page. You could use Javascript to keep adding `<iframes>` of pages inside each other, creating the effect you desire.  [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)  has an article on how to use `<iframes>`.

Edit: Please note that is definitely not the best way to go about the task at hand. The same effect could be achieved using CSS and Javascript, without the need to load in multiple web pages.

Comment: Seems overkill for this problem.

Comment: I was responding to the question, but I would definitely agree it wouldn't be the best way to go about the issue. I'll add in a comment about that.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt really give me a good result. Every square was in another border created by the iframe.

Comment: See the comment about it not being a good way to go about the task. But your question asked to be able to load in another web page, which this would enable you to do.

Comment: That's true but i had already tested iframe and it doesnt seem me a good solution. For real, i was thinking to something like ajax.